# Printing the largest number from the outputs (collatz conjecture-python)

Tags: python, for-loop, math, collatz

I need help for printing the largest number from the multiple outputs. How can I modify this code to do so?

```python
x = int(input("Enter a number : "))
while(x!=1):
    if(x%2==0):
        x  = x/2
        print("\n",x)
    else:
        x = 3*x+1
        print("\n",x)
```

[image]

When I typed "20" as the input, I get a list of numbers and I can easily say that 16 is the largest out of the outputs. But it is really hard when the input is big. I need a code to print out the largest number from the outputs

Comment: There is a single input in this code. Should the `input` be part of the loop?

Comment: @mozway Kindly re-read the question. It has been edited.

Comment: *"I get a list of numbers and I can easily say that 10 us the largest out of the outputs."* Well, no, there is 16 which is larger than 10. And there is 20 which is larger than 16, if you count the first number in the sequence.

Comment: You should use `x // 2` rather than `x / 2`. In python, `//` is integer division; `/` is floating-point division.

Comment: @stef oops my bad!

Comment: @TerrificLagger The simplest way to modify your code to get what you want is to remove the `print` from the loop, and maintain a variable `m` representing the maximum element encounter so far. At every iteration of the loop, compare `m` and `x`, and update `m` to be the greater of the two. Then after the loop, print only `m`. But since python already has a `max` function in its standard library, Peter's answer is a better solution (although harder to understand if you're not familiar with python's "generators" and the `yield` keyword).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) that generates the Collatz sequence and then use the `max()` function to find the largest number:

```
def collatz_sequence(x):
    yield x

    while x > 1:
        x = x // 2 if x % 2 == 0 else 3 * x + 1
        yield x

print(max(collatz_sequence(5)))   # Output: 16
```

Comment: Kindly re-read the question, it has been edited. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @TerrificLagger Kindly re-read (and test) the answer, and try to modify it to suit your needs ;). In this case, if you don't want to include the original number in the sequence, just remove the firrst `yield x` which is before the while-loop.

Comment: @TerrificLagger I do not understand how to change my answer based on your edit. Do you want me to exclude the input value? Do you also want to print all intermediate values?

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden I figured it out, thanks! Your code helped me a lot mate.